# Enable lightning button on value entered

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninginput, lightning-button

I have two lightning:button and a lightning:input field. What I have seen in some places is that. Some buttons are enabled only when values are entered in the text boxes. Is this achievable in lightning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the `disabled` attribute of the `ui:button` || `lightning:button` components. Here is an example.

```
<aura:component>

  <aura:attribute name="username" type="String" default="" />


  <ui:inputText required="true" value="{!v.username}" label="Username" updateOn="keyup" />
  <ui:button disabled="{!empty(v.username)}" class="slds-button_brand" label="Submit" />

</aura:component>
```

**PS:** I have used the `ui:*` components here you can use the `lightning:*` components.